# Update Problem from command line with sudo

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, sudo

When I type into command line `sudo apt-get update` I'm unable to complete all the update and I'm also unble to install any type of other software. The command line give to me this error

```
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The list of errors:

```
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: i don't see any error. you have ppa there that are gone. They lead to unexisted links. remove those ppa and use google to find if there is a new ppa for those specific apps you may have installed from those ppa

Answer (score 4):

Remove these lines from your sources list files:

```
ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu
ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu
```

Have a look in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder and remove the corresponding files, and then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

again.

Answer (score 3):

For the errors:

```
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
```

It's because the authors have no **xenial** repository defined.

Change the first one from xenial to **vivid**.

Change the second one from xenial to **trusty**.

The easiest place to change this is by using `Software & Updates`, locate the failing ppas, and edit the repository name. Or, if you don't need them, just delete them.